# wprintf not printing special characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I'm trying to print the argument used to execute the program with the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale>

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
    wprintf(L"Parameter sent: %s", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I using the following command to execute the program:

```
AppName.exe SomeText-éãö
```

It prints:

```
Parameter sent: ?????????????
```

Comment: `main`'s second argument must have type `char*[]`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `℅Ls`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not in Windows land

Comment: You need set the correct code page of the console as well.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bky3b5dh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), multibyte-character environment is created by default if `main` is used. A wide-character environment is created by default if `wmain` is used.

Thus, it turns out that there are two ways to solve this problem. I'll use Chinese characters as an example, by setting *Command Arguments* to "中国" (meaning "China") in *Debugging* tab of project's *Property Pages*.

Basically, you need set the code page used by the console input and output, in addition to the language locale. Otherwise, the console may not display your characters correctly. That's why you see "??????.." because the characters just don't exist in the code page the console currently uses.

1.Use multi-byte character set.

```
// Since we use MBCS, narrow-character version main should be used
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // You console may not use the code page you want.
   printf ("%d\n", GetConsoleCP());
   printf ("%d\n", GetConsoleOutputCP());

   // To read/write Chinese characters, we set code page to 936.
   SetConsoleCP(936);
   SetConsoleOutputCP(936);

   // Set C++ locale. Same to "Chinese_China.936" here.
   locale old = locale::global(locale(""));
   locale cur;
   printf ("old locale: %s\n", old.c_str());
   printf ("new locale: %s\n", cur.c_str());

   printf("Parameter sent: %s\n", argv[1]);
   getchar();
}
```

which outputs,

```
1252
1252
old locale: C
new locale: Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
Parameter sent: 中国
```

2.Use Unicode.

```
// Since we use Unicode, wide-character version wmain should be used
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
   // You console may not use the code page you want.
   printf ("%d\n", GetConsoleCP());
   printf ("%d\n", GetConsoleOutputCP());

   // To read/write Chinese characters, we set code page to 936.
   SetConsoleCP(936);
   SetConsoleOutputCP(936);

   // Set C++ locale. Same to "Chinese_China.936" here.
   locale old = locale::global(locale(""));
   locale cur;
   printf ("old locale: %s\n", old.c_str());
   printf ("new locale: %s\n", cur.c_str());

   wprintf(L"Parameter sent: %ls\n", argv[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

which outputs,

```
1252
1252
old locale: C
new locale: Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
Parameter sent: 中国
```